# Dot Net Framework 4.8 installs a lots of extra dependencies while installing nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

> I have a project let say A in which some of the solution are targeting
>   .Net Framework 4.8.  -- Project A
>
> When I install nuget a package.(Nuget package Dependencies :  v4.6.2 ,v4.8
>   v4.7, v4.7.1, v4.7.2, v2.1, v3.0, v3.1, v2.0, v2.1)  -- Nuget B

It install a lots of extra dependencies stating that:

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package '' with
>   respect to project ''', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'

Dependencing are as following: -

- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Builder
- Microsoft.Extensions.Loggin
- Microsoft.Extensions.Options
  -Microsoft.Extensions.Http

Is there any solution that it does not install these dependencies?.

Comment: Most likely not. What package are you trying to install?

Comment: @yaakov This package is not open for everyone its used inside our company.

Comment: Nuget package is Targeting as following:-

<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp3.0;net462;net47;net471;net472;netstandard2.1;netcoreapp3.1;net48</TargetFrameworks>